# How to Change database name in Linq Vb.net

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database Linq dbml
I need to change the database name before creating

```
  Dim dt As New DataSchool()
  dt.Connection.Open()
  dt.CreateDatabase()
```

[image: Database]

[image: Code]

Comment: Do you have a connection string for L2S in the config file and/or on the Settings page of the project properties? If so, what is it?

Comment: "Data Source=LAPTOP-AJM33RB1\TESTSERVER;Integrated Security=True;" 
this is connectionstring

Comment: That's the connection string in the code. I asked you whether you had a connection in Settings or in the config file. Are you saying that you do and that it's the same, or did you not answer the question that I actually asked.

Comment: it's connection string in config file 
  <add name="Hekma_School_Mangment_System.Settings.dtSchoolsConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-AJM33RB1\TESTSERVER;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: What is a `DataSchool`? Where is its class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This Method

```
Sub CreatesqldatabaseMSQL()
            Try
                Using connect As New DataSchool(GetSQLConnectionString(True))
                    connect.CreateDatabase()
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

**GetSQLConnectionString** This Function Return SQLconnection string

```
  Public Function GetSQLConnectionString(ByVal includeDatabase As Boolean) As String
        Dim builder As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        'Build a connection string from the user input.'
        builder.DataSource = Msql.datasource
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = Msql.IntSec
        If builder.IntegratedSecurity = False Then
            builder.UserID = Msql.username
            builder.Password = Msql.password
        End If
        If includeDatabase Then
            builder.InitialCatalog = Msql.DatabaseName
        End If
        Return builder.ConnectionString
    End Function
```

Msql.Server, Msql.DatabaseName and etc this is Structure, You can change database name From here

```
 Public Structure Msql
        Shared datasource As String
        Shared IntSec As Boolean
        Shared username As String
        Shared password As String
        Shared DatabaseName As String
    End Structure
```